# svn update without moving into that directory

Tags: svn

I need to do a number of svn updates on a server.  Is it possible to do an `svn update` without moving into that directory?

Just trying to keep things tidy instead of cd'ing around all over the server :-)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just

```
svn update /path/to/dir/to/update
```

Works just fine.  There's no need to be in the directory when updating it.

Likewise, you can update individual files.

```
svn update /path/to/dir/to/update/config.ini
```

(tested on Subversion 1.6.17)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ svn help update

update (up): Bring changes from the repository into the working copy.
usage: update [PATH...]

  If no revision is given, bring working copy up-to-date with HEAD rev.
  Else synchronize working copy to revision given by -r.

  For each updated item a line will start with a character reporting the
  action taken.  These characters have the following meaning:
```

so, things like

> svn update /home/naishe/workspace

will work

Comment: @Dogsbody, to elaborate on this answer: `svn help` will give you the list of SVN commands. `snv help <command>` or `svn <command> --help` will then give you help on that particular command.

Answer (score 0):

An extra for you, as I liked your question. Let's assume the list of directories you are handling is a, b, c ... z.

You can do this to spare you some extra lines :

for DIR in a b c ... z; do
  svn update $DIR;
done

(Bash syntax).

And if you are in a hurry, and want those updates to occur simultaneously (will require that the directories are in separate trees, i.e., that they have no common .svn in any of their parent directories), then you'll run the updates in background !

for DIR in a b c ... z; do
  svn update $DIR **&**
done